# A health related and text based dataset

Tags: data-request, medical, social-media

I am looking for a **labeled** text based dataset which is health related for a machine learning project.

I found some interesting papers like "Evaluation of Facebook and Twitter Monitoring to Detect Safety Signals for Medical Products: An Analysis of Recent FDA Safety Alerts.", "Evaluation of the Feasibility of Screening Patients for Early Signs of Lung Carcinoma in Web Search Logs." and other similar publications but neither of them had a public dataset.

Where can I find such a dataset?

Edit: My topic of interest is extracting medical data from social media, like the paper I have mentioned. But I'd appreciate other suggestions.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear: *labeled text based dataset which is health related* is very broad - it sounds as if any collection of health related text will do. Is that so? Why is your question labeled 'social media'? And what kind of labeling do you want - what **are** your labels - diseases?. Also, in what format do you want them, how much data do you need? Please [edit] your question to improve it. [This may help](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like).

Comment: I added the topic to the question. About other things, It can be anything. I just want it for a supervised machine learning project.

Comment: Would Medline/PubMed with Mesh annotations count?

Comment: @Grimaldi Yes, but please provide me a link to an article which has used that dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't  find what I was looking for, but finally used this dataset:
http://www.biocreative.org/resources/corpora/biocreative-v-cdr-corpus/